# Make a for loop for a dataframe to substract dates and put it in a variable

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe that looks like this with a lot of products

| Product | Start Date |
| --- | --- |
| 00001 | 2021/08/10 |
| 00002 | 2021/01/10 |

I want to make a cycle so that it goes from product to product subtracting three months from the date and then putting it in a variable, something like this.
date[]=''

```
for dataframe in i:
    date['3monthsbefore']=i['start date']-3 months
    date['3monthsafter']=i['start date']+3 months
    date['product']=i['product']
    "Another process with those variables"
```

And then concat all this data in a dataframe I´m a little bit lost,
I want to do this because I need to use those variables in another process, so I't is possible to do this?.

Answer (score 3):

Using pandas, you usually don't need to loop over your DataFrame. In this case, you can get the 3 months before/after for all rows pretty simply using `pd.DateOffset`:

```
df["Start Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Start Date"])
df["3monthsbefore"] = df["Start Date"] - pd.DateOffset(months=3)
df["3monthsafter"] = df["Start Date"] + pd.DateOffset(months=3)
```

This gives:

```
  Product Start Date 3monthsbefore 3monthsafter
0   00001 2021-08-10    2021-05-10   2021-11-10
1   00002 2021-01-10    2020-10-10   2021-04-10
```

---

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Product": ["00001", "00002"], "Start Date": ["2021/08/10", "2021/01/10"]})
```

Comment: The thing Is I need to put those variables in a SQL Query so I need to save those variables and put it on the Query, thats why y put the for.

Comment: If you need to build queries from these variables, you could try using `zip` and looping through. For example `for sdate, edate in zip(df["3monthsbefore"], df["3monthsafter"]):
    q = f"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date > {sdate} AND date < {edate}"` (excuse any bad SQL syntax)

Comment: I see you have more experiences in this and to save all those querys and then concat them.